# Multiple Events From one Button TKINTER

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, tkinter

I realize some people may have already asked this question but i'd like to task it in my way in order to get a specific response.

So im using Tkiner in pyhton 2.7.

Basically I want a single button which is displayed by default with the initial text value of First Click and a Label which says Blah by default. 
When "First Click" has been clicked it should change the text value inside that button to "Second Click" and also change the text value inside the Label to BlahBlah. And once again when "Second Click" has been clicked it should again change the text value of "second Click" to be "Third Click" and also again change the value of the Label to be "BlahBlahBlah" and now clicking the "Third Button" should change nothing at all and everything should remain as is.

Please note that i'm a newbie and I would prefer the easiest(dumbest) level possible so I can start learning from somewhere. Basically something that would make sense to a dummy.

Iv'e done a lot of research and have failed to understand how to do it and have resorted to asking my specific question to everyone that is willing to help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a counter to keep track of these clicks and use conditions to change the text accordingly.

```
import tkinter as tk

def switch():

     if root.counter <= 1:
          if not root.counter:
               a_label['text'] = 'Second Click'
               a_button['text'] = 'Second Button'
          else:
               a_label['text'] = 'Third Click'
               a_button['text'] = 'Third Button'
          root.counter += 1

root = tk.Tk()
root.counter = 0
a_label = tk.Label(root, text='Blah')
a_label.pack()
a_button = tk.Button(root, text='First Click', command=switch)
a_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pythonista, that really helped! I hope this also helps other people :).